How to draw a node in some given coordinates
Can`t draw node with specified coordinates on gViewer.
Try to use code from this question Change Node position in MSAGL , but it doesn`t work.
        Form form = new ();
        GViewer viewer = new ();
        Graph graph = new ("graph");
        graph.AddNode("test");
        Microsoft.Msagl.Core.Geometry.Point position = new(100, 100);
        graph.FindGeometryNode("test").Center = position;//exception in this line
        viewer.NeedToCalculateLayout = false; 
        viewer.Graph = graph;
        form.SuspendLayout();
        viewer.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        form.Controls.Add(viewer);
        form.ShowDialog();

It throws NullReferenceException.
Message:
        "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." 

Stack:

MsaglTestApplication.dll!MsaglTestApplication.Program.Main() Line 23    C#


Find detailed example how to fix this problem on winforms. Was test this code it`s worked. On github:
https://github.com/microsoft/automatic-graph-layout/blob/master/GraphLayout/Samples/PopulateGViewerWithPrecalculatedDrawingGraph/Program.cs
Update:
Here is code of answer:
        private static void SetNodeBoundary(Microsoft.Msagl.Drawing.Node drawingNode) {
        var font = new System.Drawing.Font(drawingNode.Label.FontName, (float)drawingNode.Label.FontSize);
        StringMeasure.MeasureWithFont(drawingNode.LabelText, font, out double width, out double height);
        drawingNode.Label.GeometryLabel = new Microsoft.Msagl.Core.Layout.Label();
        drawingNode.Label.GeometryLabel.Width = width;
        drawingNode.Label.GeometryLabel.Height = width;
        drawingNode.Label.Width = width;
        drawingNode.Label.Height = height;
        int r = drawingNode.Attr.LabelMargin;
        drawingNode.GeometryNode.BoundaryCurve = CurveFactory.CreateRectangleWithRoundedCorners(width + r * 2, height + r * 2, r, r, new Point());
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var gviewer = new GViewer();
        var form = TestFormForGViewer.FormStuff.CreateOrAttachForm(gviewer, null);
        gviewer.NeedToCalculateLayout = false;
        var drawingGraph = new Microsoft.Msagl.Drawing.Graph();
        var a = drawingGraph.AddNode("a");
        var b = drawingGraph.AddNode("b");
        drawingGraph.AddEdge("a", "b");
        var geometryGraph = drawingGraph.CreateGeometryGraph();
        SetNodeBoundary(a);
        SetNodeBoundary(b);
        a.GeometryNode.Center = new Point(0, 50);
        b.GeometryNode.Center = new Point(50, -500);
        var router = new Microsoft.Msagl.Routing.SplineRouter(geometryGraph, new EdgeRoutingSettings());
        router.Run();
        geometryGraph.UpdateBoundingBox();
        gviewer.Graph = drawingGraph;
        Application.Run(form);
    }


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. Can you [edit] your answer to summarize the relevant guidance from the link? Answers on Stack Overflow can certainly link to additional information, but they should stand on their own even if the page they are linking to is later (re)moved. This is important because often, over time, the linked pages are no longer available, which is frustrating for future members of the community.

graph.AddNode("test") returns the added node, so you can use it directly, instead of searching for it with FindGeometryNode afterwards.
var node = graph.AddNode("test");
node.Center = new(100, 100);

(Disclaimer: I never used this library. So, my code is not tested.)

Thank you, but it gives error cs 1061, not defined definition of Center in variable of Node type.

If you have this library installed (which I have not), you can discover the members of a node with Intellisense. By digging into the code on Github there seems to be a Center property in Rectangle. So, probably: node.BoundingBox.Center.

Thank you for advice I appreciate that, but i have already look into this library and can`t find anything useful for solving problem. I guess I was looking in the wrong place, but unfortunately I don’t know where to look.

Us IntelliSense in Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code

Yes i know about this feature of Visual Studio and i use it in my work. From rewriting with your recommendations to this:
Node n = graph.AddNode("test");
Microsoft.Msagl.Core.Geometry.Point position = new(100, 100);
n.GeometryNode.Center = position;
NullReferenceException is not dissappearing.

Then probably the Node n does not contain a GeometryNode. Maybe you have to add one manually because Node is empty after creation.

As i know Node contain a GeometryNode, but after creation Node it equal a null. That`s  one of reason why is code throwing exception.
